# How to print html source to console with phantom-crawler

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I just downloaded and installed phantom-crawler for nodejs. I copy and pasted the following script into a file called crawler.js:

```
var Crawler = require('phantom-crawler');

// Can be initialized with optional options object 
var crawler = new Crawler();
// queue is an array of URLs to be crawled 
crawler.queue.push('https://google.com/');
// Can also do `crawler.fetch(url)` instead of pushing it and crawling it 
// Extract plainText out of each phantomjs page 
Promise.all(crawler.crawl())
.then(function(pages) {
  var texts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    var page = pages[i];
    // suffix Promise to return promises instead of callbacks 
    var text = page.getPromise('plainText');
    texts.push(text);
    text.then(function(p) {
      return function() {
        // Pages are like tabs, they should be closed 
        p.close()
      }
    }(page));
  }
  return Promise.all(texts);
})
.then(function(texts) {
  // texts = array of plaintext from the website bodies 
  // also supports ajax requests 
  console.log(texts);
})
.then(function () {
  // kill that phantomjs bridge 
  crawler.phantom.then(function (p) {
    p.exit();
  });
})
```

I'd like to print the complete html source (in this case from the google page) to the console.

I searched a lot, but I haven't found anything similar, so how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the `content` instead of the `plainText` promise.

The module [phantom-crawler](https://github.com/tqn/phantom-crawler) uses the module [node-phantom-simple](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-phantom-simple), which uses [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs).

You can find the list of properties you can call in the [phantomjs wiki](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage).

```
var Crawler = require('phantom-crawler');

// Can be initialized with optional options object
var crawler = new Crawler();
// queue is an array of URLs to be crawled
crawler.queue.push('https://google.com/');
// Can also do `crawler.fetch(url)` instead of pushing it and crawling it
// Extract plainText out of each phantomjs page
Promise.all(crawler.crawl())
.then(function(pages) {
  var allHtml = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    var page = pages[i];
    // suffix Promise to return promises instead of callbacks
    var html = page.getPromise('content');
    allHtml.push(html);
    html.then(function(p) {
      return function() {
        // Pages are like tabs, they should be closed
        p.close()
      }
    }(page));
  }
  return Promise.all(allHtml);
})
.then(function(allHtml) {
  // allHtml = array of plaintext from the website bodies
  // also supports ajax requests
  console.log(allHtml);
})
.then(function () {
  // kill that phantomjs bridge
  crawler.phantom.then(function (p) {
    p.exit();
  });
})
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. This is very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome, but you know I juste checked the source code ;) !

Comment: I am new in node js technology, I try out to figure how all the things work together and believe me I checked the source code but I don’t understand the coffee-script.